# Mutt e-mail client get stuck

Tags: command-line, 16.04, mutt, email-client

I am experimenting with Mutt under Ubuntu 16.04. It almost always feezes after a few minutes on the index page. What is the cause for this?
I didn't use extensive setup, I just added three standard Gmail account which work perfectly otherwise.

Comment: IMAP or POP3 over SSL? And have you followed a guide to get yourself up and running?